# Как исправить unsupported operand type(s) for Add: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

```
rev = input('Оцените развлекательный коаплекс:')
rev = rev.lower()

searching1 = rev.find('весело')
searching2 = rev.find('увлекательно')
searching3 = rev.find('развлечения')

number = searching1 + '/' +  searching2 + '/' + searching3

print('Результат анализа:', number)
```

Пишу на питоне
выводит ошибку в этой строке

```
number = searching1 + '/' +  searching2 + '/' + searching3
```

Comment: В первую очередь стоит спросить себя, что вы ожидаете получить в результате, прибавляя к числу, например, `-1` строку `'/'`

Answer (score 2):

```
rev='О как  ты получишь развлечения увлекательно  весело'

rev = rev.lower()

searching1 = rev.find('весело')
searching2 = rev.find('увлекательно')
searching3 = rev.find('развлечения')

number = str(searching1) + '/' +  str(searching2) + '/' + str(searching3)

print('Результат анализа:', number)
```

---

```
searching1 - Тип int 
'/' - Тип строка
Прообразовываем целое(int) в строку str(searching1)
```